# CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER not working in PHP even with setting CURLOPT_CAINFO

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I am trying to enable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` in PHP, but when I call `curl_exec()` it is returning `false` with no other error message or indication of why its breaking. Here is what I have:

```
$curl_object = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/srv/assets/ssl/ca-bundle.pem");
curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

curl_setopt($curl_object, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($curl_object);
```

As soon as I set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` it works. The `CURLOPT_CAINFO` file is th offical ca-cert.pem from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that site you are connecting to is using certificate signed by one of CA listed in this file?

Comment: Yeah seems valid, it id https://freegeoip.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this can help to debug the issue:

```
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Comment: I set `verbose` to true but don't any more output. Where does this go?

Comment: Probably in the webserver log. You can redirect it to a file like this:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen("/tmp/curl_debug.txt", "w+"));

Comment: Ahhhh, here is the error: `* Peer's certificate issuer is not recognized: 'CN=COMODO SSL CA,O=COMODO CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB' In the browser though no warnings.

Comment: Or you can use "curl_error()" but this does give extra info!